# &nbsp;を持つdivタグだけにCSSを適用させたいです

Tags: jquery

jQuery初心者です。

div内に`&nbsp;`が入っていたらdivにcssを追加したいのですが
下記のコードでは動きません。
どういう書き方をしたら動くのか教えてください。

```
$(function() {
　if($('.pf-list').has('&nbsp;')) {
　$(this).css({
  　　backgroundColor: '#ccc';
　　});
　}
});
```

Answer (score 4):

文字参照`nbsp`はユニコード符号位置でいう`U+00A0`に相当します（[仕様](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#entity-nbsp), [参考](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm)）。
このことから[:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)を用いて要素の選択が可能です。

```js
$('div:contains("\u00A0")').css({ backgroundColor: '#ccc' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>apple</div>
<div>banana</div>
<div>che&nbsp;rry</div>
<div>durian</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

通常はテキストののセレクターは以下のAPIを使えるのですが、
https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

`&nbsp;`だけは特殊なものは直接テキストをgrepしないと使えないです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275742/can-i-select-an-element-that-contains-nbsp-within-its-html

```
$(function() {
  var regEx = /&nbsp;/gm;
  var elements = $(".pf-list").filter(function(index, ele) {
     if(regEx.test($(ele).html())) {
       　$(ele).css("background-color", '#ccc');
    }
  });   
});
```